# Sending get/post requests on a different thread in Qt

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt

I'm developing an application in Qt where I need to send asynchronous post/get requests to another server from my client. My app already has one thread and I wanted to create a different thread with its own event loop to send post/get requests.

Is it possible to do this with

1. subclassing the QThread,
2. initiating event loop in reimplemented run method of the subclass,
3. have a method for sending the requests?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to do anything since QNetworkAccessManger makes all requests asynchronously.
Read more http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.7/qnetworkaccessmanager.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I just need to have an event loop to work with QNetworkAccessManager.And i wanted to create another thread with the event loop. Can i create class that takes care of networking and move that object to that thread with the new event loop?

Comment: chances are you already have an event loop in your main thread

Comment: I do have an event loop but it is not qt based . That is why wanted to create another thread with a new event loop.

Comment: You don't need to have another thread for QNetworkAccessManager. It will work fine in you main thread. You just need to call it post/get methods and slot for receiving replies, if you like. The whole work will be done in another thread, main thread will just receive the result.

Comment: So, why do you want to use qt?

Comment: because i wanted to add ssl http requests. qt suits well for it. I can't have qnetworkaccessmanager in main thread there is not qt event loop there

Comment: I would recommend you to look at libcurl or poco C++ for this purpose. Using qt only for making some request is a huge overhead.

Comment: @weisert is right. Using Qt just for it isn't a good idea, and I don't know if it is possible to send QEvents between a qt-based event loop and your one that is not qt-based.

Answer (score 0):

You must get in mind that a **QObject** has a thread affinity that it is acquired "where" object is instantiate. That means Qt doesn't know receive events (and signals) from another thread than object's thread if there is not a event loop created. Take a look this [link](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/thread-basics.html#qobject-and-threads) for more info.

A good way is to create a class that implements your logic, and instantiate it into run method of a specific subclass of **QThread**. Let me explain with code:

```
class WorkerClass : public QObject
{
   // Your logic
  public slots:
     void doWork();
};

class ThreadClass : public QThread
{
   WorkerClass*  m_worker;
   WorkerClass*  getWorker();
   ...
   void run()
   {
      // A new thread is created
      WorkerClass instance; // Get thread affinity
      m_worker = &instance;
      exec(); // Start event loop
      m_worker = 0;
   }
   ....
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
   QCoreApplication app(arc, argv);
   ThreadClass pThread = new ThreadClass();
   pThread->start();
   pThread->getWorker()->doWork(); // do work into worker's thread

   // Other tasks

   pThread->quit();
   delete pThread;

   app.quit();
}
```

Every event or signal emitted to WorkerClass will "jump" to its thread to be processed.

I hope this will help you.

Comment: How i create and delete the ThreadClass? Can i have it run forever with the main thread of the app?

Comment: @user3065039 ThreadClass is like any other class. It is a wrapper for threads in your current OS indeed. I have added how to use it.

Comment: You can also use [QObject::moveToThread](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qobject.html#moveToThread). Then you wouldn't have to subclass `QThread` at all. You should also wait for the thread to finish after calling `QThread::quit()` before deleting it.

Comment: I wanted to have 2 permanent threads in my application. One that does stuff and another permanent thread that is responsible of the networking requests. The app is a daemon so i need to networking thread to work all the time.

Comment: Jairo wanted to ask you. I implemented more or less like in the template. I have WorkerClass that inside of it has QnetworkAccessManager and in the constructor i  connected this way connect(&manager, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)), SLOT(slotFinished(QNetworkReply*)));   My question is how later i collect the responses in QNetworkReply

Comment: @user3065039 I have never used QNetworkAccessManager. But a quick look to doc, it seems to create its own thread to wait to _put_, _post_ and _get_ requests in order to not block the current thread. So responses to these calls will be sended using _finished_ signal to the connected slots, in your case _slotFinished_.